# why are colors being updated multiple times

Tags: react-native, lifecycle

Why are my random colors being updated multiple times?  Is the right way to control this behavior through a lifecycle event?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView, FlatList, SectionList, View, Button, SegmentedControlIOS } from 'react-native';
import contacts, {compareNames} from './contacts';
import {Constants} from 'expo';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}


const Row=(props)=>(
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <Text style={{color:props.color}} >{props.name}</Text>
    <Text >{props.phone}</Text>
  </View>
)

const renderItem=(obj)=> {

     return(<Row  {...(obj.item)} color={getRandomColor()} />)

}

const ContactsList = props => {
  const renderSectionHeader=(obj) =><Text>{obj.section.title}</Text>
    const contactsByLetter = props.contacts.reduce((obj, contact) =>{
     const firstLetter = contact.name[0].toUpperCase()
     return{
       ...obj,
       [firstLetter]: [...(obj[firstLetter] || []),contact],
     }
   },{})

   const sections = Object.keys(contactsByLetter).sort().map(letter=>({
      title: letter,
      data: contactsByLetter[letter],
   }))

  return(
  <SectionList
    keyExtractor = { (item, key) => key.toString() }
    renderItem={renderItem}
    renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
    sections={sections}
  />
)}

ContactsList.propTypes ={
  renderItem: PropTypes.func,
  renderSectionHeader: PropTypes.func,
  contacts: PropTypes.array,
  sections: PropTypes.func
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state={show: false, selectedIndex: 0, contacts: contacts}

  toggleContacts=()=>{
    this.setState({show:!this.state.show})
  }

  sort=()=>{
    this.setState({contacts: [...this.state.contacts].sort(compareNames)})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="toggle names" onPress={this.toggleContacts}  />
        <Button title="sort" onPress={this.sort}  />
        <SegmentedControlIOS
          values={['ScrollView', 'FlatList','SectionList']}
          selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={(event) => {
            this.setState({selectedIndex: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex});
          }} />
        {this.state.show && this.state.selectedIndex === 0 &&
          <ScrollView >
            {this.state.contacts.map(contact=>(
              <Row  {...contact}/> ))}
          </ScrollView>}
        {this.state.show && this.state.selectedIndex === 1 &&
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.contacts}
            keyExtractor = { (item, index) => index.toString() }
            renderItem={renderItem}>
          </FlatList>}
        {this.state.show && this.state.selectedIndex === 2 &&
          <ContactsList
            contacts={this.state.contacts}>
          </ContactsList>}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    // alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight + 25,
  },
  row: {
    padding:20,
  },
});
```

```html
const NUM_CONTACTS = 10

const firstNames = ['Emma','Noah','Olivia','Liam','Ava','William','Sophia','Mason','Isabella','James','Mia','Benjamin','Charlotte','Jacob','Abigail','Michael','Emily','Elijah','Harper','Ethan','Amelia','Alexander','Evelyn','Oliver','Elizabeth','Daniel','Sofia','Lucas','Madison','Matthew','Avery','Aiden','Ella','Jackson','Scarlett','Logan','Grace','David','Chloe','Joseph','Victoria','Samuel','Riley','Henry','Aria','Owen','Lily','Sebastian','Aubrey','Gabriel','Zoey','Carter','Penelope','Jayden','Lillian','John','Addison','Luke','Layla','Anthony','Natalie','Isaac','Camila','Dylan','Hannah','Wyatt','Brooklyn','Andrew','Zoe','Joshua','Nora','Christopher','Leah','Grayson','Savannah','Jack','Audrey','Julian','Claire','Ryan','Eleanor','Jaxon','Skylar','Levi','Ellie','Nathan','Samantha','Caleb','Stella','Hunter','Paisley','Christian','Violet','Isaiah','Mila','Thomas','Allison','Aaron','Alexa','Lincoln']

const lastNames = ['Smith','Jones','Brown','Johnson','Williams','Miller','Taylor','Wilson','Davis','White','Clark','Hall','Thomas','Thompson','Moore','Hill','Walker','Anderson','Wright','Martin','Wood','Allen','Robinson','Lewis','Scott','Young','Jackson','Adams','Tryniski','Green','Evans','King','Baker','John','Harris','Roberts','Campbell','James','Stewart','Lee','County','Turner','Parker','Cook','Mc','Edwards','Morris','Mitchell','Bell','Ward','Watson','Morgan','Davies','Cooper','Phillips','Rogers','Gray','Hughes','Harrison','Carter','Murphy']

// generate a random number between min and max
const rand = (max, min = 0) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min

// generate a name
const generateName = () => `${firstNames[rand(firstNames.length - 1)]} ${lastNames[rand(lastNames.length - 1)]}`

// generate a phone number
const generatePhoneNumber = () => `${rand(999, 100)}-${rand(999, 100)}-${rand(9999, 1000)}`

// create a person
const createContact = () => ({name: generateName(), phone: generatePhoneNumber()})

// compare two contacts for alphabetizing
export const compareNames = (contact1, contact2) => contact1.name > contact2.name

// add keys to based on index
const addKeys = (val, key) => ({key, ...val})

// create an array of length NUM_CONTACTS and alphabetize by name
export default Array.from({length: NUM_CONTACTS}, createContact).map(addKeys)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your component is triggering the render method multiple times. This happens mostly when you use `setState` method, since everytime your `state` changes the render method is triggered.

You may have 2 options to handle this:

1) Identify where your component is being rerendered and treat it if this behavior is unnecessary. You can use `console.log` to debug it.

2) You can avoid the random method to be called multiple times if you call it only in your `componentDidMount` method. Since `componentDidMount` is called only once in the component lifecycle, all functions inside of it will not be triggered when the component rerenders, only when it mount again. (I think this is the solution)

Let me know if it helps.